# Redirecting a virtual apache webpage

Tags: apache-http-server, website, web, redirection

I know there are already several posts asking about redirecting webpages but I can not seem to find exactly what I am looking for.

I have a website (for example www.example.com) that needs to be redirected:

1. example.com
2. www.example.net
3. example.net

Should all be redirected to www.example.com

I found [Apache redirect from one domain to another domain](https://superuser.com/questions/122810/apache-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another-domain) but I am not sure how to add it to my file located in **/etc/apache2/sites-available** This is what the file currently looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/www.example.com-error_log
    TransferLog logs/www.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need a redirect (HTTP code 301/302)? If it is enough that all domain names deliver the same content, you can just add a `ServerAlias example.com www.example.net example.net` inside the `VirtualHost` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add them one after the other. Example:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/www.example.com-error_log
    TransferLog logs/www.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAlias example.net
    redirect permanent / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can have a `VirtualHost` without `ServerName`, so that `ServerAlias` in the second `VirtualHost` block should rather be `ServerName`.

Comment: [Link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost) -> `A ServerName should be specified inside each <VirtualHost> block. If it is absent, the ServerName from the "main" server configuration will be inherited.)` Depends on setup, but he probably needs it. Good catch.

Comment: There may be some DNS CNAME configuration in order here as well.